# Are there Perl modules recommended for reading and creating epub files?

Tags: epub, programming

Are there any Perl modules that support the full epub format reading and writing? Ideally something that is maintained, so it includes or will include [epub 3](http://idpf.org/epub) compatibility.

Comment: I would suggest that this is really a question for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow would reject it because it is a request for a tool recommendation.

Comment: Do you mind explaining more on what a "Perl module" is for the few that do not know what you are referring to.  +1 for the question though and I hope it does stay on-topic.  @EdCottrell I hope we can keep more code related questions in regards to ebooks. It would add a better benefit to the community.

Comment: @EdCottrell - strange... similar questions used to be popular and non-closed on SO back when I was active. Thinks must have evolved :)

Comment: @Matt_2.0 - [Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) is a popular dynamically typed programming language. Among its main claims to notability is [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/modules/), which is a free repository of 10000s of "modules" (programming libraries designed for a specific task and usable from your Perl program) for doing anything, from statistics to web site scraping to Excel/Word file reading/writing to sky-is-the-limit.

Comment: @DVK - personally, I think many such questions *are* good fits for SO, but they tend to rack up close votes and down votes very quickly these days. To be fair, other sites (Programmers, Database Administrators, and Webapps) are often good fits for those questions.

Comment: Tool recomendation questions are strongly off-topic on SO. Programmers are very strange SE, originally a place for off-topic questions from SO, nowadays Dilbert-comic requests (questions with comic content are highly upvoted, all others are likely to be downvoted). Actually, I think, if that question is on-topic anywhere, it will be here.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. - Perl modules are libraries, not tools. Did they ban "which library should I best use for task X" by now as well? \*sigh\*

Comment: @ŁukaszL. - I could never make heads or tails of Programmers. As far as I could figure out, it was tailor made for productivity and career type Qs, but I never managed to find a calling to post there. Most my stuff is migrated SO material.

Answer (score 3):

[EPUB::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/EPUB%3a%3aParser) is available and supports epub3 only.